# Django: Reference between models

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Help!

I have the following 2 models:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    receiveaddress = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=8, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)


class Deposits(models.Model): 
    receiveaddress = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=8, default=0)

    user = ?????????????????

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    accounted = models.BooleanField(default=False)  

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.receiveaddress)
```

**Example:**
[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZsN6.jpg)

**My problem:**

I want "Deposits.user" to **automatically** reference the user to which this 'receiveaddress' belongs.  In the example, that's TIM. I've wasted 6 hours trying to figure it out, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try something like `user = models.ForeignKey(Account)`

Comment: Thanks! But this gives me the option to select any user in accounts, in this case --> Bob, Alice or Tim. I need it to show Tim only.

Comment: actually this represent many to one case, for each account there wlll me multiple doposits. Look in other way, there is many to one relation between deposit and account.

Comment: You are absolutely right..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it' just a design matter. Why do you put two fields that have the same information, since the `user` has account with `receiveaddress`, adding the user as foreign key will be enough and cleaner, I suggest the following:

```js
class Account(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    receiveaddress = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=8, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)


class Deposit(models.Model): 
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=8, default=0)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="deposits")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    accounted = models.BooleanField(default=False)  

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.account.receiveaddress)
```

*NB: As a convention, models name should be always singular*

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!